# Quartz cluster and redis jobStore

Tags: quartz-scheduler

Is there any redis jobStore able to support a quartz cluster?

Have anybody been able to build that?

By other side, what's exactly a quartz cluster? I mean, is it able to have two services running the same `quartz.properties` file pointing to a redis?

**EDIT**

I've tried with this redis job store but it seems doesn't supprt quartz clustering:

> JobStore class 'net.joelinn.quartz.jobstore.RedisJobStore' props could not be configured. [See nested exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No setter for property 'isClustered']

`quartz.properties`:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=office-scheduler-service
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval=20000

# thread-pool
org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=2
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread=true

org.quartz.jobStore.class = net.joelinn.quartz.jobstore.RedisJobStore
org.quartz.jobStore.host = redisbo
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
```

Comment: https://github.com/jlinn/quartz-redis-jobstore

Comment: Does it support quartz clustering?

Comment: sure, you can try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to configure cluster, please check the source code, it is already clustered

[image]

Comment: Does this mean if I am using RedisJobStore, I do not need to add any locks? It is taken care of all by Redis JobStore, along the same lines as Quartz supports clustering when using JDBC JobStore? I could not find any documentation along those lines. Can you please point me to it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Quartz JDBC documentation](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering.html) explains how it handles executing jobs in a cluster of application nodes. RedisJobStore extended that to utilize the Redis storage, and it will work in a cluster mode (Quartz cluster - not Redis cluster) by default without requiring you to enable that.

Basically Quartz uses a shared database to record which scheduler instance is currently working on a job, as opposed to direct node communication among application schedulers. When a scheduler instance picks up a job, it safely registers its instance id with the running job and persists it in the database. This support by the job store is evident in the [schema](https://github.com/RedisLabs/redis-quartz/blob/master/schema/schema.txt) used by RedisJobStore, indicated by the *blocked_by* fields.